# Is there any way to modify transform widget thickness?

Tags: modeling, transforms

is possible to tweak transform tool's thickness?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to change the gizmo size you can do it through **Preferences --> Viewport --> Gizmo Size**

[image]